# wsgi:error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, wsgi

I've looked everywhere for a solution. I can't figure out what is the matter. Maybe I'm not seeing an easy mistake or sometime. I'm using `pyenv` because during development I used python version 3.8.2 and Django 3.0.5. I also have a virtualenv setup and all the packages are installed when i do pip freeze. When I run `which django` nothing returns. I'm using apache 2.4 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Thanks in advance. Any extra info needed let me know.

Here's the config file:

```
WSGIPythonPath /etutors-site/site-dj/etutorproject

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog /etutors-site/site/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /etutors-site/site/access.log combine

        alias /static /etutors-site/site/public/static
        <Directory /etutors-site/site/public/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /etutors-site/site-dj/etutorproject/etutorproject>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>


        WSGIDaemonProcess etutors-site python-path=/etutors-site/site-dj/etutorproject python-home=/etutors-site/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup etutors-site
        WSGIScriptAlias / /etutors-site/site-dj/etutorproject/etutorproject/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the exact error:

```
[Fri May 15 21:12:27.762544 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656260556544] [remote 72.51.112.97:22446] mod_wsgi (pid=9063): Target WSGI script '/etutors-site/site-dj/etutorproject/etutorproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri May 15 21:12:27.762661 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656260556544] [remote 72.51.112.97:22446] mod_wsgi (pid=9063): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etutors-site/site-dj/etutorproject/etutorproject/wsgi.py'.
[Fri May 15 21:12:27.762899 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656260556544] [remote 72.51.112.97:22446] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 15 21:12:27.762931 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656260556544] [remote 72.51.112.97:22446]   File "/etutors-site/site-dj/etutorproject/etutorproject/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Fri May 15 21:12:27.762940 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656260556544] [remote 72.51.112.97:22446]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri May 15 21:12:27.762961 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656260556544] [remote 72.51.112.97:22446] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Fri May 15 21:12:28.281276 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656294127360] [remote 72.51.112.97:21820] mod_wsgi (pid=9063): Target WSGI script '/etutors-site/site-dj/etutorproject/etutorproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri May 15 21:12:28.281420 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656294127360] [remote 72.51.112.97:21820] mod_wsgi (pid=9063): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etutors-site/site-dj/etutorproject/etutorproject/wsgi.py'.
[Fri May 15 21:12:28.281587 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656294127360] [remote 72.51.112.97:21820] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 15 21:12:28.281652 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656294127360] [remote 72.51.112.97:21820]   File "/etutors-site/site-dj/etutorproject/etutorproject/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Fri May 15 21:12:28.281669 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656294127360] [remote 72.51.112.97:21820]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri May 15 21:12:28.281710 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 9063:tid 140656294127360] [remote 72.51.112.97:21820] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```